# How to add two values in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, addition

We are just starting to learn about arrays in my Java course, so I'm having problems. I want to multiply "quantity" by "cost" so it will print out the total cost, but right now it prints out 0 for the totalCost. Here is the driver:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem2 {

public static void main(String[] args){

String purchase, date;
double quantity, cost;

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("How many different types of items are you purchasing?");
    int answer = myScanner.nextInt();
    myScanner.nextLine(); // pick up the enter key

    Basket[] myBasket = new Basket[answer];
    for(int j = 0; j < answer; j++) {

        System.out.println("Please enter the item you purchased.");
        purchase = myScanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the date.");
        date = myScanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the quantity.");
        quantity = myScanner.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Please enter the cost.");
        cost = myScanner.nextFloat();
        myScanner.nextLine(); // pick up the enter key  

        myBasket[j] = new Basket(purchase, date, quantity, cost);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< answer; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(myBasket[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the Basket class:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Basket {

    private String purchase, date;
    private double quantity, cost, totalCost;

    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public Basket(String purchase, String date, double quantity, double cost)
    {
        this.purchase = purchase;
        this.date = date;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public void Calculations()
    {
        totalCost = cost * quantity;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Purchase: " + purchase
        + "\nDate: " + date
        +"\nQuantity: " + quantity
        +"\nCost:" + fmt.format(totalCost);
    }
}
```

Comment: On different note, it's not a great idea to have a separate method that you have to call to get the internal state correct. It's probably best not to make `totalCost` a field at all, but if you have to, you should call `calculations` (method names start with lowercase) from the constructor and any setters.

Comment: When do you call `Calculations`?  I would better to have a method call `getTotalCost` and return the result of calculation rather than assigning it a field value

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Calculations(); from where you are calling it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Calculations();` to `toString()`

```
public String toString()
{
    Calculations();
    return "Purchase: " + purchase
    + "\nDate: " + date
    +"\nQuantity: " + quantity
    +"\nCost:" + fmt.format(totalCost);
}
```

OR since the calculations method is public you can call it from the main method with `myBasket[j].Calculations();`

after

`myBasket[j] = new Basket(purchase, date, quantity, cost);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want totalCost to be populated, you could call Calculations method when you are creating the instance of Baskets like:

```
myBasket[j] = new Basket(purchase, date, quantity, cost);
myBasket[j].Calculations();
```

This will now calculate the total cost and save it in in stance variable which you can print later on.

Answer (score 0):

After last line in main(), add the below code,

```
float total=0.0;
for (int i = 0; i< answer; i++)
{
    //System.out.println(myBasket[i]);
      total+=myBasket[2]*myBasket[3];
}
System.out.println("total cost:"+total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ”Calculations” method is not being invoked. 
I thing you wanted to invoke it in the last line of the constructor.

By the way - java convention is lower case at the beginning of a method name, and it's better to name it by what it does - ”calculateTotalCost” for example